# Model > whereHas > Multiple Connection > Cross Database | Not Working

Tags: laravel

- Laravel Version: **7.X.X**
- PHP Version: **PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2020 11:38:52)**
- Database Driver & Version: **Ver 8.0.20 for Win64 on x86_64**

#### Description:

In multiple connection project all work, but we need to use whereAs method but not work.
We have checked online searching all the forums of the framework but have not found the solution to our problem.
we have multiple connections in the same project one manages in particular the user database and it all works by changing the connection in the model class.

As in this example the method in particular does not work other methods yes.

```php
Route::get('/test', function ($event = null) {
    echo User::with('categories')->get();
    echo User::whereHas('categories')->get(); // this method break (not change connection)
});
```

### break:

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lumen.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from`users`where exists (select * from`categories`inner join`user_category`on`categories`.`id`=`user_category`.`category_id`where`users`.`id`=`user_category`.`user_id`and`categories`.`deleted_at`is null) and`users`.`deleted_at`is null)`

On the result, first method work fine. Other method not property. i think not change connection

#### User Class belongsToMany:

```php
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = "lumen";

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->setConnection('ciao')->belongsToMany(
            Category::class,
            'user_category')
            ->withPivot('user_role');
    }
```

#### Category Class belongsToMany:

```php
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = "helpdesk";

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'user_category'
        )
            ->withPivot('user_role');
    }
```

We have tried to force db changes connection but not work...

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Create Multiple Connection and use belongsToMany Function in Model